# Page load times using a Scanner (IE5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC project which I have build as a SPA using knockoutjs and sammy.
I put this script in the page head.

```
<script>
   var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
</script>
```

and at the end of the body, I put this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/required")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/views")

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            var millisecondsLoading = endTime - startTime;
            // Put millisecondsLoading in a hidden form field
            // or Ajax it back to the server or whatever.
            alert(millisecondsLoading);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The scripts that are being loaded are these:

```
' For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
Public Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
    bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/core.css"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/required").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/json2.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
                "~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js",
                "~/Scripts/knockout.validation.js",
                "~/Scripts/sammy-0.7.5.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/app/views").Include(
                "~/Scripts/app/_common.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/_app.datamodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/_app.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/common.viewmodels.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/error.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/login.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/home.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/cut-lengths.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/move-stock.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/transfers.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/allocations.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/lot-enquiry.viewmodel.js",
                "~/Scripts/app/_run.js"))

    ' Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
    ' visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
End Sub
```

Now, if I run this using IE5 on my development machine I get an alert that is between 200 and 300 ms. This is good. 
But, when I run this on the scanner, it takes over 20000 ms (20 seconds) to load.

Here are the times for each script as I add them, in order (starting with jQuery)

- 5 seconds (jQuery on it's own)
- 6 seconds (jQuery, json2)
- 6 seconds (jQuery, json2, jQuery-cookie)
- 8 seconds (jQuery, json2, jQuery-cookie, knockoutjs)
- 9 seconds (jQuery, json2, jQuery-cookie, knockoutjs, sammy)

Now, I start adding my view models to see what affect these have:

- 9 seconds (app dataModel)
- 10 seconds (app dataModel, viewModel)
- 11 seconds (app dataModel, viewModel and common)

Each other view model takes around a second to load.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? If so, how did you fix it?
I am at a loss because we have another application that loads around the same amount of scripts and it is pretty much instant.

Please help!

Comment: JavaScript in ancient (IE5 is close to *fifteen years* old) browsers is slow. It's just a fact of life.

Comment: like I have said, we have a site that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 5 is not supported, so I wouldn't expect it to work very well:

### [KnokcoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)

> Supports all mainstream browsers, even ancient ones **IE 6+**, Firefox
>   3.5+, Chrome, Opera, Safari (desktop/mobile)

### [JQuery](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

> jQuery 1.x    **Internet Explorer 6+**

### [Sammy](http://sammyjs.org/faq)

> In general Sammy aims to support all modern and current browsers
>   across all plugins and the core. This includes:
>   **IE >= 8**

Comment: I know that all too well, but as I have said we already have a site that works fine. Just because it isn't supported, doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Comment: Well your other sites obviously are using the libraries diferently.. Why are the users stuck on IE5?